# What the difference between Release|AnyCPU and Release|ARM

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, windows-runtime

I'm working on WinRt version of my class library dll. Finally, after the huge "code cleanup" my project is on building step and I have two ways. To build the solution with **Release|AnyCPU** as usually or build it with **Release|ARM** (Which unclear for me). Which dependencies my dll will get or avoid in process of building, what will be different, will there a specific IL optimizations on a second way?

Comment: The ARM platform is meaningless in managed code, it gets jitted at runtime.  Remove platforms that don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only using managed code, there's no reason not to use **Release|AnyCPU**. This way the same package will be used for all three platforms (ARM, x86 and x64).

On the other hand, if your project references natively compiled library, you'll need to set a specific platform, like **Release|ARM**, that your native library is compiled for. If the native library is installed as an extension (e.g. SQLite for Windows Runtime), you'll be able to compile your app for all 3 target platforms, each one referencing the appropriate native library, though they will need to be individual packages instead of a single universal one.

You'll still be able to submit your app to the store as a single app even if it has 3 separate packages, one for each platform.